# Variable name determines success or failure of Keras load_model (Lambda layer problem)

Tags: python, keras

Consider the following benign-looking code snippet:

```
K=10    # include to cause error; leave out or use N=10 and load_model succeeds!
model = tf.keras.models.load_model( 'model.h5' )
```

To elaborate on the comment: if the code runs as is, the following error trace is produced. If I use N (or X or C etc) instead of K, the model loads fine. If K is defined after the `load_model()` line, the model also loads fine. But as is, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Alchemy\Software\Test\Deep Learning\models\tf\loadspec.py", line 80, in <module>
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model( 'model.h5' )
  File "D:\Alchemy\Software\Test\Deep Learning\models\tf2.2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\save.py", line 184, in load_model
    return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
  File "D:\Alchemy\Software\Test\Deep Learning\models\tf2.2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\hdf5_format.py", line 177, in load_model_from_hdf5
    model = model_config_lib.model_from_config(model_config,
  File "D:\Alchemy\Software\Test\Deep Learning\models\tf2.2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\model_config.py", line 55, in model_from_config
    return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "D:\Alchemy\Software\Test\Deep Learning\models\tf2.2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\serialization.py", line 105, in deserialize
    return deserialize_keras_object(
  File "D:\Alchemy\Software\Test\Deep Learning\models\tf2.2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 369, in deserialize_keras_object
    return cls.from_config(
  File "D:\Alchemy\Software\Test\Deep Learning\models\tf2.2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 399, in from_config
    model.add(layer)
  File "D:\Alchemy\Software\Test\Deep Learning\models\tf2.2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py", line 456, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Alchemy\Software\Test\Deep Learning\models\tf2.2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 213, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
  File "D:\Alchemy\Software\Test\Deep Learning\models\tf2.2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 922, in __call__
    outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Alchemy\Software\Test\Deep Learning\models\tf2.2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\core.py", line 1191, in call
    if K.is_sparse(inputs):
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'is_sparse'
```

I know too little python to make sense of that... but it seems like `K` is somehow so very badly scoped that the `K` I was using in my code at the top level gets confused with some other `K` deep in Keras's `core.py`. That sounds very bad. But it also sounds like the root of the problem is in the separate module that saves the `model.h5` file.

In that separate module, K is defined/used as follows:

```
# train_labels are integers in range 0-??? - convert to one-hot...
train_labels = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(train_labels)
K = len(train_labels[ 0 ])
...
model = Sequential()
# Hidden Dense layer + Lambda layer to implement Leaky ReLU ommitted...
model.add(Dense(K, activation='softmax', name='Output'))
```

That seems very reasonable - determine the number of outputs from the data. But then how does that variable number of outputs lead to a model that appears to (and on some level does) save successfully... but leads to the downstream problem if I use `K`? Is this a problem with my use of Keras... or the Keras core?

Subsequent discovery: it's something to do with the `Lambda()` layer that implements my Leaky ReLU. Here are three options for the omitted hidden layer code above, only the first of works without problems... but does so by sacrificing the desired leaky nature of the ReLU activation:

```
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu', name='Hidden'))    # only this saves without any problems
    -= OR =-
    model.add(Dense(10, name='Hidden'))
    model.add(Lambda(lambda x: tf.keras.activations.relu(x, alpha=0.01), name='LeakyReLU'))
    -= OR =-
    model.add(Dense(10, name='Hidden'))
    lrelu = lambda x: tf.keras.activations.relu(x, alpha=0.01)
    model.add(Lambda(lrelu, name='LeakyReLU'))
```

Comment: why you need to define K=10 before loading the model ?

Comment: K is the variable I use to define the number of outputs. I need to know the number of outputs so that I can convert the test data label format into a one-hot representation (sometimes certain labels are missing...) But the one-hot step is a red-herring, so i just wrote K=10 to prove that it was as simple as defining K as an int that caused the issue.

Comment: I guess there are two work arounds: don't use K, or do the one-hot conversion after loading the model. But... both feel like working around the bug rather than fixing it.